# How can I implement the functionality of awt.CardLayout in my javaFX 2.0 application?

Tags: javafx-2

In my javaFX 2.0 app, I need to replace a component which is used awt.CardLayout. Cardlayout has a functionality as a stack which displays the top component in stack. And also we can manually configure which is to be displayed.

In javaFX 2.0, there is a layout called StackPane. But It doesn't seems like Cardlayout.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no CardLayout, but you can use TabPane or simply switch groups:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {

    VBox vbox = new VBox(5);

    Button btn = new Button("1");
    Button btn2 = new Button("2");

    final Pane cardsPane = new StackPane();
    final Group card1 = new Group(new Text(25, 25, "Card 1"));
    final Group card2 = new Group(new Text(25, 25, "Card 2"));

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            cardsPane.getChildren().clear();
            cardsPane.getChildren().add(card1);
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            cardsPane.getChildren().clear();
            cardsPane.getChildren().add(card2);
        }
    });

    vbox.getChildren().addAll(btn, btn2, cardsPane);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));
    stage.setWidth(200);
    stage.setHeight(200);
    stage.show();

}
```

Comment: I tried with TabPane. But it displays a tab menu. So I used the way you have suggested here.It works fine for my requirement. Thanks Sergey. :)

Comment: Note, there is new control named `Pagination` in 2.2 release which may fit your needs even better.

Comment: This answer may not be the best as it forces a re-draw of your `Group`. This means if your `Group` has a lot of information on it, it will introduce a noticeable lag on the switch.

Answer (score 13):

Another option is to use a `StackPane` and set the visibility of all but the curent `Pane` to `false`. Not ideal, but another way of thinking about the problem

Comment: Actually, your answer is better than the answer above. This prevents the re-drawing of the Pane. I had a Pane that had about 12 tabs on them, and using the solution to this question, it would take around 200ms to switch to it. Using your answer, it became instant.

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Using metasim's answer, here is the full code (also made the buttons act more like toggle buttons):

```
public void start(Stage stage)
{

    VBox vbox = new VBox(5);

    RadioButton btn = new RadioButton("1");
    RadioButton btn2 = new RadioButton("2");

    ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
    btn.setToggleGroup(group);
    btn2.setToggleGroup(group);

    btn.getStyleClass().remove("radio-button");
    btn.getStyleClass().add("toggle-button");        


    btn2.getStyleClass().remove("radio-button");
    btn2.getStyleClass().add("toggle-button");        

    final Pane cardsPane = new StackPane();
    final Group card1 = new Group(new Text(25, 25, "Card 1"));
    final Group card2 = new Group(new Text(25, 25, "Card 2"));

    cardsPane.getChildren().addAll(card1, card2);
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        public void handle(ActionEvent t)
        {
            showNodeHideNodes(cardsPane.getChildren(), card1);
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        public void handle(ActionEvent t)
        {
            showNodeHideNodes(cardsPane.getChildren(), card2);
        }
    });

    vbox.getChildren().addAll(btn, btn2, cardsPane);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));
    stage.setWidth(200);
    stage.setHeight(200);
    stage.show();

}

private static void showNodeHideNodes(List<Node> nodes, Node nodeToShow)
{
    for (Node node : nodes)
    {
        if (node.equals(nodeToShow))
        {
            node.setVisible(true);
        } else
        {
            node.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

}
```