# JavaFX - TabPane/Tab How to make tab title invisible?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I'm new in JavaFX and have a little troubles:

I have an TabPane with several Tabs and I wanna make Tab titles invisible. So, user should not change Tabs by clicking on titles, but it will be changed in different way from menu..

How to make this Tab titles invisible/hidden? That's the question. I don't wanna hide whole Tabs or disable or anything like that, just titles.

Or maybe you have another, completely different idea, how to solve this in JavaFX. Maybe with another controls???

Thanks for any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conclusion of my research: This is not possible to do this in JavaFX. TabPane captions can be located on the top, left, right and bottom of the control, but cannot be hidden.

Answer (score 6):

If you are not using `Tabs` then you don't need `TabPane`.

You can just introduce a list of content panes and switch them according to menu commands.

You can find a code example in next question: [How can I implement the functionality of awt.CardLayout in my javaFX 2.0 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309802/how-can-i-implement-the-functionality-of-awt-cardlayout-in-my-javafx-2-0-applica)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this by wrapping `TabPane` in `AnchorPane` (root container) and setting up TabPane's topAnchor to negative number as much as needed.

### Java code:

```
...
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(myTabPane, -29.0);
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(myTabPane, 0);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(myTabPane, 0);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(myTabPane, 0);
...
```

### Also in FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TabPane fx:id="myTabPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="-29.0">
        <tabs>
          <Tab fx:id="tab1" text="Tab 1">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label text="Tab 1" />
                        <Button layoutX="35.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Go to Tab 2 (non-functional currently)" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab fx:id="tab2" text="Tab 2">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label text="Tab 2" />
                        <Button layoutX="35.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Go to Tab 1 (non-functional currently)" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```