# Javafx Stackpane show similar CardLayout Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, javafx, stackpanel, cardlayout

I use three buttons to display each child panel in stackpane,but when I click the button,it displays different panels per click

Example

btn0-> pane 0,pane 1and pane 2

btn1-> pane 0,pane 1and pane 2

btn2-> pane 0,pane 1and pane 2

I just want it to display a specific panel for specific buttons in java swing cardLayout should I do?

btn0-> pane 0

btn1-> pane 1

btn2-> pane 2

Please help me!

```
@FXML
void btn0(ActionEvent event) {
    stackConsole.getChildren().get(0).toFront();
}

@FXML
void btn1(ActionEvent event) {
    stackConsole.getChildren().get(1).toFront();
}

@FXML
void btn2(ActionEvent event) {
    stackConsole.getChildren().get(2).toFront();
}
```

Comment: more answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309802/how-can-i-implement-the-functionality-of-awt-cardlayout-in-my-javafx-2-0-applica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your needs you may be interested in the `TabPane` class.

Of course implement similar funtionality in the controller class. Calling `toFront()` for a child will not have the desired effect however, since

1. All children remain in the `stackConsole`
2. `toFront` just moves the `Node` it is called for to the last child position of the parent.

What you're trying to achieve however seems to be replacing the children of `stackConsole`. This can be done by injecting the different children to the controller class and using `ObservableList.setAll` to replace the contents. The `<fx:define>` tag can be used for children not initially shown in the scene.

#### Example

**FXML**

```xml
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fxml.ReplaceController">
    <center>
        <StackPane fx:id="stackConsole">
            <children>
                <!-- use multiply blend mode to demonstrate other children are not present
                     (result would be black otherwise) -->
                <Region fx:id="r0" blendMode="MULTIPLY" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" />
                <fx:define>
                    <Region fx:id="r1" blendMode="MULTIPLY" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" />
                    <Region fx:id="r2" blendMode="MULTIPLY" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: green;" />
                </fx:define>
            </children>
        </StackPane>
    </center>
    <left>
        <VBox prefHeight="200.0" spacing="10.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="1" onAction="#btn0"  />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="2" onAction="#btn1" />
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="3" onAction="#btn2" />
            </children>
            <padding>
                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
            </padding>
        </VBox>
    </left>
</BorderPane>
```

**Controller**

```
public class ReplaceController {
    @FXML
    private Region r1;
    @FXML
    private Region r2;
    @FXML
    private Region r0;
    @FXML
    private Pane stackConsole;

    @FXML
    private void btn0(ActionEvent event) {
        stackConsole.getChildren().setAll(r0);
    }

    @FXML
    private void btn1(ActionEvent event) {
        stackConsole.getChildren().setAll(r1);
    }

    @FXML
    private void btn2(ActionEvent event) {
        stackConsole.getChildren().setAll(r2);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank fabian.If you wish you can help me problems later, it's too hard for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210296/hide-and-show-splitpane-with-webview-javafx