# Displaying AnchorPane on top of JavaFX Application

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

My main application runs in a `JFXTabPane`, having multiple tabs.
In a special case I want to load another `AnchorPane` on top of the entire application.

**RootController.java**

```
JFXTabPane tabPane = new JFXTabPane();

tab = new Tab("Tab 1");
tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

borderPane.setCenter(tabPane);
loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fxml1.fxml"));
parent = loader.load();
tab.setContent(parent);
Controller controller = loader.getController();

/* ... Loading more tabs ... */


/* Loading the additional `AnchorPane`, that needs to be loaded at a later point */
AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fxml2.fxml"));
```

**Fxml1Controller.java**

```
Pane pane;

/* Registering that AnchorPane in the Controller */
public void setPane(Pane p) {
    this.pane = p;
}
```

My approach is to set the pane to visible an bring it to front when needed:

```
private void showPane(ActionEvent event) {
    pane.setVisible(true);
    pane.toFront();
    System.out.println(pane);
}
```

But it doesn't change anything.

So, how can I display the `AnchorPane` on top of my `JFXTabPane`?

Comment: Add borderPane and pane into StackPane. Show\hide StackPane item depends on condition.

Comment: See answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309802/how-can-i-implement-the-functionality-of-awt-cardlayout-in-my-javafx-2-0-applica)