# JavaFx 12 : About stages

Tags: javafx

I wonder if you can do this:

a main stage of the content
and a menu stage within that content stage

like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyJBk.png)

i try make but i got this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLfSg.gif)

my fxml:

```
<StackPane fx:id="root" prefWidth="311.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.semeq.controllers.Test">
    <!-- Header -->
    <BorderPane>
        <top>
            <VBox spacing="20">
                <JFXToolbar>
                    <leftItems>
                        <JFXRippler maskType="CIRCLE" style="-fx-ripple-color:WHITE;">
                            <StackPane fx:id="titleBurgerContainer">
                                <JFXHamburger fx:id="titleBurger">
                                    <HamburgerBackArrowBasicTransition />
                                </JFXHamburger>
                            </StackPane>
                        </JFXRippler>
                        <Label>Material Design</Label>
                    </leftItems>
                </JFXToolbar>
            </VBox>
        </top>

        <!-- Content Area -->
        <center>
            <JFXDrawer fx:id="drawer" defaultDrawerSize="250" direction="LEFT">
                <styleClass>
                    <String fx:value="body" />
                </styleClass>
            </JFXDrawer>
        </center>
    </BorderPane>
</StackPane>
```

controller:

```
package com.semeq.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDrawer;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXHamburger;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXRippler;
import com.jfoenix.transitions.hamburger.HamburgerBackArrowBasicTransition;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

@Controller
public class Test {
    @FXML
    private Pane root;

    @FXML
    private StackPane titleBurgerContainer;

    @FXML
    private JFXHamburger titleBurger;

    @FXML
    private JFXRippler optionsRippler;

    @FXML
    private StackPane optionsBurger;

    @FXML 
    private VBox box;

    @FXML
    private JFXDrawer drawer;

    public void initialize() {
        try {
            box = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Home.fxml"));
            drawer.setSidePane(box);
            for (Node node : box.getChildren()) {
                if(node.getAccessibleText() != null) {
                     System.out.println("xdasdd");
                    node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (ex) -> {
                        switch(node.getAccessibleText()) {
                        case "Gerenciar" :
                            try {
                                StackPane gerenciar = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Gerenciar.fxml"));
                                root.getChildren().addAll(gerenciar);
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        HamburgerBackArrowBasicTransition transition = new HamburgerBackArrowBasicTransition(titleBurger);

          drawer.setOnDrawerOpening(e -> {
            transition.setRate(1);
            transition.play();
          });
          drawer.setOnDrawerClosing(e -> {
              transition.setRate(-1);
              transition.play();
          });
          titleBurgerContainer.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
              if (drawer.isClosed() || drawer.isClosing()) {
                  drawer.open();
              } else {
                  drawer.close();
              }
          });
    } 
}
```

i don't know if this is possible
a stage for all the content
and a stage for the menu within that content

In other words, I wanted a Main Stage
and another stage being part of this main stage and when you clicked on the main stage it would appear

Comment: A stage that is part of a stage? I don't know about any OS/API that would allow you to place a window within a window. Of course it's possible to add nodes to a existing scene. If you use a `StackPane` as parent, the node is positioned by the `StackPane`. Unless any parameters are set, this centers all children in the `StackPane`...

Comment: @fabian 
thanks fabian could you help me? Where did I go wrong in this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement the functionality of awt.CardLayout in my javaFX 2.0 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309802/how-can-i-implement-the-functionality-of-awt-cardlayout-in-my-javafx-2-0-applica)

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/RestaurantOrdersDuplicateFX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, but you are doing it all wrong. You are making everything very complex. Whenever you work with `JFXDrawer`. Try to make a seperate `fxml` file for the drawer itself, and another `fxml` file for the `root` container, where you want your drawer to be placed. In this way you will have two `fxml` files. It will make things much simpler.

Here's my approach for your problem. I hope it helps you!

1. **Main.java** (Main launch file) -

   ```
   package application;

   import javafx.application.Application;
   import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
   import javafx.stage.Stage;
   import javafx.scene.Parent;
   import javafx.scene.Scene;


   public class Main extends Application {
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
       try {
           //this is the directory - package_name/fxml_file.fxml
           Parent root = 
           FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/container.fxml")); 
           Scene scene = new Scene(root);
           primaryStage.setScene(scene);
           primaryStage.setTitle("Material Design JFX Navigation Drawer");
           primaryStage.show();
       } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
    }
   }
   ```
2. **NavigationController.java** (Controller Class) -

   ```
   public class NavigationController implements Initializable {
       @FXML private AnchorPane anchorPane;
       @FXML private StackPane stackPane1, stackPane2, stackPane3, stackPane4;
       @FXML private JFXHamburger hamburger;
       @FXML private JFXDrawer drawer;

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
       StackPane[] stackPaneArray = {stackPane1, stackPane2, stackPane3, stackPane4};
       for(int i = 0;i<stackPaneArray.length;i++){
       stackPaneArray[i].setVisible(false);;
       }
       try {
           VBox box = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/drawer.fxml"));   //this is the directory - package_name/fxml_file.fxml
           drawer.setSidePane(box);

           for(Node node : box.getChildren()){
               if(node.getAccessibleText()!=null){
                   node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e) ->{
                       switch(node.getAccessibleText()){
                       case "Gerenciar_1":
                       stackPane1.setVisible(true);
                       stackPane2.setVisible(false);
                       stackPane3.setVisible(false);
                       stackPane4.setVisible(false);   
                       break;
                   case "Gerenciar_2":
                       stackPane1.setVisible(false);
                       stackPane2.setVisible(true);
                       stackPane3.setVisible(false);
                       stackPane4.setVisible(false);
                       break;
                   case "Gerenciar_3":
                       stackPane1.setVisible(false);
                       stackPane2.setVisible(false);
                       stackPane3.setVisible(true);
                       stackPane4.setVisible(false);   
                       break;
                   case "Gerenciar_4":
                       stackPane1.setVisible(false);
                       stackPane2.setVisible(false);
                       stackPane3.setVisible(false);
                       stackPane4.setVisible(true);    
                       break;

                       }
                   });
               }
           }
           HamburgerBackArrowBasicTransition transition = new HamburgerBackArrowBasicTransition(hamburger);
           transition.setRate(-1);
           hamburger.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,(e) -> {
               transition.setRate(transition.getRate()*-1);
               transition.play();

               if(drawer.isShown()){
                   drawer.close();
               }else{
                   drawer.open();
               }
           });
       } catch (IOException e1) {
           e1.printStackTrace();
       }                       
      }       
     }
   ```
3. **container.fxml** (fxml file for the container) -

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDrawer?>
   <?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXHamburger?>
   <?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
   <?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
   <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

   <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" 
   minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="390.0" 
   prefWidth="460.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102" 
   xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
   fx:controller="application.NavigationController">
   <children>
     <JFXDrawer fx:id="drawer" defaultDrawerSize="173.0" layoutY="24.0" 
    prefHeight="367.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
     <MenuBar prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="460.0">
       <menus>
         <Menu mnemonicParsing="false">
              <graphic>
                 <JFXHamburger fx:id="hamburger" />
              </graphic>
         </Menu>
       </menus>
     </MenuBar>
     <StackPane fx:id="stackPane1" layoutX="140.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="367.0" prefWidth="320.0">
    <children>
       <Label text="StackPane 1">
          <font>
             <Font name="System Bold" size="17.0" />
          </font>
       </Label>
    </children></StackPane>
     <StackPane fx:id="stackPane2" layoutX="140.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="367.0" prefWidth="320.0">
    <children>
       <Label text="StackPane 2">
          <font>
             <Font name="System Bold" size="17.0" />
          </font>
       </Label>
    </children></StackPane>
     <StackPane fx:id="stackPane3" layoutX="140.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="367.0" prefWidth="320.0">
    <children>
       <Label text="StackPane 3">
          <font>
             <Font name="System Bold" size="17.0" />
          </font>
       </Label>
    </children></StackPane>
     <StackPane fx:id="stackPane4" layoutX="140.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="367.0" prefWidth="320.0">
    <children>
       <Label text="StackPane 4">
          <font>
             <Font name="System Bold" size="17.0" />
          </font>
       </Label>
    </children></StackPane>
    </children>
   </AnchorPane>
   ```
4. **drawer.fxml** (fxml file for the drawer) -

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
   <?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
   <?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
   <?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

   <VBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" 
   minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="390.0" 
   prefWidth="173.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102" 
   xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
   <JFXButton accessibleText="Gerenciar_1" buttonType="RAISED" 
   focusTraversable="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="176.0" 
   text="Gerenciar">
    <font>
       <Font size="15.0" />
    </font>
    <graphic>
       <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="USER" size="30" wrappingWidth="43.0" />
    </graphic>
    </JFXButton>
    <JFXButton accessibleText="Gerenciar_2" buttonType="RAISED" 
    focusTraversable="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="178.0" 
    text="Gerenciar">
    <font>
       <Font size="15.0" />
    </font>
    <graphic>
       <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="USER" size="30" wrappingWidth="43.0" />
    </graphic>
    </JFXButton>
    <JFXButton accessibleText="Gerenciar_3" buttonType="RAISED" 
    focusTraversable="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="178.0" 
    text="Gerenciar">
    <font>
       <Font size="15.0" />
    </font>
    <graphic>
       <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="USER" size="30" wrappingWidth="43.0" />
    </graphic>
    </JFXButton>
    <JFXButton accessibleText="Gerenciar_4" buttonType="RAISED" 
    focusTraversable="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="178.0" 
    text="Gerenciar">
    <font>
       <Font size="15.0" />
    </font>
    <graphic>
       <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="USER" size="30" wrappingWidth="43.0" />
    </graphic>
    </JFXButton>
    </children>
    </VBox>
   ```

Here's the screenshot of what I did -

[image][image]

Take a look. I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Yes that's it thank you so much but there's one thing when the menu is open it has a shadow on bg outside the menu

Comment: It is an in-built ripple effect, I guess. Also, please kindly upvote my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: u can help me? 
I'm trying and couldn't make it

Comment: Thank you so much @Felipe. Take a look at [Material Design Navigation Drawer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgV8dDP9DtM). And learn more and more about JavaFX Navigations Drawers. You will surely find a way. All the very best :)

Comment: I had done something like this, but I found nothing of how to use this shadow

Comment: This way I had done I had succeeded but I had trouble with the screens

Comment: What you were doing is that you were loading a new `StackPane` on the `Button` click. Do you want it like that?

Comment: yes i have this menu and on each menu click i would load another fxml

Comment: Another approach would be to create four instances of `StackPane` and play with the **visibility** of it. I have edited my previous answer. Take a look at the `NavigationController.java` and `container.fxml` from my answer. I hope this helps :)